# how to import CSV document in MySql database if file has comma and double quotes in rows?

Tags: mysql, import, mysqlimport

I am trying to import a .csv file into MySQL document with these settings

```
Columns separated with: ,
Columns enclosed with: "
Columns escaped with: "
Lines terminated with: \n
```

but some rows in my CSV file have these special characters - `, " '` ex - `lee's` `"custom"` `option1, option2` etc. so it shows an error on these rows and doesn't include them in the table. How to solve this?

Comment: If your CSV file is incorrectly formatted then it will be impossible to import it. You have to show the actual example though

Comment: Load the whole line into UDV then parse it in SET clause. Or fix CSV file structure.

Comment: My CSV file consists of a question and it's four options but some questions and options are like this - Q1 **in Multi-Channel Funnel reports, how are default conversions credited?** option1 - **Second to last campaign, search or ad** option2 - **Last campaign, search, or ad** Q2 - **What is not considered a default “medium” in Google Analytics?** option1 - **Medium, Source, and 'Content'** so it doesn't include rows with these special character - `, " '`.